# Websocket HTTPS to HTTP downgrade

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have a pretty simple question!
I want to load a WS:// Server on a HTTPS connection. Is there any way i can force a WS over a WSS without user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an nginx server to proxy it.

This would mean you connect to your nginx server instead of your final destination.

First, you'll need to set up [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) (or some other certificate).

Technically you could generate your own certificate, but if you do this, then the browser will not trust this connection - which you can work around by visiting this site directly and accepting it before loading your other site. It's a pain though. Trust me. LetsEncrypt works really well once you've set it up. But you may have to do it another way if you do not have a domain name.

An nginx rule like this would be a good starting point;

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name  _;

  location / {
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    proxy_pass http://your.destination.com;  # Note the http rather than ws.

    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/yoursite.net.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/yoursite.net.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/yoursite.net.fullchain;
  }
}
```

Once you have this set up, you connect to this server, which wraps your websocket connection in a certificate, and forwards it.